# Invalid Column Name or Identity_Insert off

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4

I have been going rounds all morning with CF EF. I think I have all issues resolved but one and I'm sure this issue is due to my lack of knowledge / understanding.

The problem is focused around one table and the mapping of said table so I'll give the definitions first then explain the problems. Here is how the table is defined:

[image]

Now I have defined the class representation as:

```
public partial class ExternalForumCredentials : BaseEntity
{
   public virtual int Customer_Id { get; set; }
   public virtual int ExternalForumBoardId { get; set; }
   public virtual string Username { get; set; }
   public virtual string Password { get; set; }
 }
```

and the mapping:

```
public ExternalForumCredentialsMap()
{
   this.ToTable("ExternalForumCredentials");
   this.HasKey(ef => ef.Id);
   this.HasKey(ef => ef.Customer_Id);
   this.HasKey(ef => ef.ExternalForumBoardId);
   this.Property(ef => ef.Username).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(100);
   this.Property(ef => ef.Password).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(100);

 }
```

Now I am not showing the controller code as I think the problem lies in my ef config. HOWEVER if I am wrong simply tell me what I need to add and I will do so immediately.

So...given that ID, Customer_Id, and ExternalForumBoardId are primary keys I defined the mapping as seen above.

With this configuration all goes well right up to an insert...then it crashes saying I am trying to do an IDENTITY_INSERT. OK that makes sense as I am assigning a value to Customer_Id and ExternalForumBoardId in the controller and since the mapping has them as keys there is a conflict.

So I change the mapping to:

```
public ExternalForumCredentialsMap()
{
        this.ToTable("ExternalForumCredentials");
        this.HasKey(ef => ef.Id);
        this.Property(ef => ef.Customer_Id);
        this.Property(ef => ef.ExternalForumBoardId);
        this.Property(ef => ef.Username).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(100);
        this.Property(ef => ef.Password).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(100);       
}
```

Now before I can even perform the insert I get an error: Invalid column name Customer_Id and of course with my limited knowledge I don't understand because I have define Customer_Id.

I have also tried HasRequired in the mapping but that won't even compile saying "the type int must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter..."

The other mapping options such as Ignore don't seem to make sense in this context.

Any help explaining what I am doing wrong would be much appreciated.

---

Db Context Interface:

```
public interface IDbContext 
{
    IDbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : BaseEntity;

    int SaveChanges();

    IList<TEntity> ExecuteStoredProcedureList<TEntity>(string commandText, params object[] parameters)
        where TEntity : BaseEntity, new();

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a raw SQL query that will return elements of the given generic type.  The type can be any type that has properties that match the names of the columns returned from the query, or can be a simple primitive type. The type does not have to be an entity type. The results of this query are never tracked by the context even if the type of object returned is an entity type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TElement">The type of object returned by the query.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="sql">The SQL query string.</param>
    /// <param name="parameters">The parameters to apply to the SQL query string.</param>
    /// <returns>Result</returns>
    IEnumerable<TElement> SqlQuery<TElement>(string sql, params object[] parameters);

    /// <summary>
    /// Executes the given DDL/DML command against the database.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sql">The command string</param>
    /// <param name="timeout">Timeout value, in seconds. A null value indicates that the default value of the underlying provider will be used</param>
    /// <param name="parameters">The parameters to apply to the command string.</param>
    /// <returns>The result returned by the database after executing the command.</returns>
    int ExecuteSqlCommand(string sql, int? timeout = null, params object[] parameters);
   }
}
```

and:

```
public static class DbContextExtensions {
    /// <summary>
    /// Loads the database copy.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="context">The context.</param>
    /// <param name="currentCopy">The current copy.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static T LoadDatabaseCopy<T>(this IDbContext context, T currentCopy) where T : BaseEntity {
        return InnerGetCopy(context, currentCopy, e => e.GetDatabaseValues());
    }

    private static T InnerGetCopy<T>(IDbContext context, T currentCopy, Func<DbEntityEntry<T>, DbPropertyValues> func) where T : BaseEntity {
        //Get the database context
        DbContext dbContext = CastOrThrow(context);

        //Get the entity tracking object
        DbEntityEntry<T> entry = GetEntityOrReturnNull(currentCopy, dbContext);

        //The output 
        T output = null;

        //Try and get the values
        if (entry != null) {
            DbPropertyValues dbPropertyValues = func(entry);
            if(dbPropertyValues != null) {
                output = dbPropertyValues.ToObject() as T;
            }
        }

        return output;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the entity or return null.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="currentCopy">The current copy.</param>
    /// <param name="dbContext">The db context.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static DbEntityEntry<T> GetEntityOrReturnNull<T>(T currentCopy, DbContext dbContext) where T : BaseEntity {
        return dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries<T>().Where(e => e.Entity == currentCopy).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    private static DbContext CastOrThrow(IDbContext context) {
        DbContext output = (context as DbContext);

        if(output == null) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Context does not support operation.");
        }

        return output;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Loads the original copy.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="context">The context.</param>
    /// <param name="currentCopy">The current copy.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static T LoadOriginalCopy<T>(this IDbContext context, T currentCopy) where T : BaseEntity {
        return InnerGetCopy(context, currentCopy, e => e.OriginalValues);
    }
}
```

and the implementation:

```
public class ObjectContext : DbContext, IDbContext
{
    public ObjectContext(string nameOrConnectionString)
        : base(nameOrConnectionString)
    {
        //((IObjectContextAdapter) this).ObjectContext.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //dynamically load all configuration
        System.Type configType = typeof(LanguageMap);   //any of your configuration classes here
        var typesToRegister = Assembly.GetAssembly(configType).GetTypes()
        .Where(type => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(type.Namespace))
        .Where(type => type.BaseType != null && type.BaseType.IsGenericType && type.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(EntityTypeConfiguration<>));
        foreach (var type in typesToRegister)
        {
            dynamic configurationInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(configurationInstance);
        }
        //...or do it manually below. For example,
        //modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new LanguageMap());



        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Attach an entity to the context or return an already attached entity (if it was already attached)
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TEntity">TEntity</typeparam>
    /// <param name="entity">Entity</param>
    /// <returns>Attached entity</returns>
    protected virtual TEntity AttachEntityToContext<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : BaseEntity, new()
    {
        //little hack here until Entity Framework really supports stored procedures
        //otherwise, navigation properties of loaded entities are not loaded until an entity is attached to the context
        var alreadyAttached = Set<TEntity>().Local.Where(x => x.Id == entity.Id).FirstOrDefault();
        if (alreadyAttached == null)
        {
            //attach new entity
            Set<TEntity>().Attach(entity);
            return entity;
        }
        else
        {
            //entity is already loaded.
            return alreadyAttached;
        }
    }

    public string CreateDatabaseScript()
    {
        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CreateDatabaseScript();
    }

    public new IDbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : BaseEntity
    {
        return base.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public IList<TEntity> ExecuteStoredProcedureList<TEntity>(string commandText, params object[] parameters) where TEntity : BaseEntity, new()
    {
        //HACK: Entity Framework Code First doesn't support doesn't support output parameters
        //That's why we have to manually create command and execute it.
        //just wait until EF Code First starts support them
        //
        //More info: http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2011/09/23/using-entity-framework-code-first-with-stored-procedures-that-have-output-parameters.aspx

        bool hasOutputParameters = false;
        if (parameters != null)
        {
            foreach (var p in parameters)
            {
                var outputP = p as DbParameter;
                if (outputP == null)
                    continue;

                if (outputP.Direction == ParameterDirection.InputOutput ||
                    outputP.Direction == ParameterDirection.Output)
                    hasOutputParameters = true;
            }
        }



        var context = ((IObjectContextAdapter)(this)).ObjectContext;
        if (!hasOutputParameters)
        {
            //no output parameters
            var result = this.Database.SqlQuery<TEntity>(commandText, parameters).ToList();
            for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
                result[i] = AttachEntityToContext(result[i]);

            return result;

            //var result = context.ExecuteStoreQuery<TEntity>(commandText, parameters).ToList();
            //foreach (var entity in result)
            //    Set<TEntity>().Attach(entity);
            //return result;
        }
        else
        {

            //var connection = context.Connection;
            var connection = this.Database.Connection;
            //Don't close the connection after command execution


            //open the connection for use
            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                connection.Open();
            //create a command object
            using (var cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                //command to execute
                cmd.CommandText = commandText;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                // move parameters to command object
                if (parameters != null)
                    foreach (var p in parameters)
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(p);

                //database call
                var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                //return reader.DataReaderToObjectList<TEntity>();
                var result = context.Translate<TEntity>(reader).ToList();
                for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
                    result[i] = AttachEntityToContext(result[i]);
                //close up the reader, we're done saving results
                reader.Close();
                return result;
            }

        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a raw SQL query that will return elements of the given generic type.  The type can be any type that has properties that match the names of the columns returned from the query, or can be a simple primitive type. The type does not have to be an entity type. The results of this query are never tracked by the context even if the type of object returned is an entity type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="TElement">The type of object returned by the query.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="sql">The SQL query string.</param>
    /// <param name="parameters">The parameters to apply to the SQL query string.</param>
    /// <returns>Result</returns>
    public IEnumerable<TElement> SqlQuery<TElement>(string sql, params object[] parameters)
    {
        return this.Database.SqlQuery<TElement>(sql, parameters);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Executes the given DDL/DML command against the database.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sql">The command string</param>
    /// <param name="timeout">Timeout value, in seconds. A null value indicates that the default value of the underlying provider will be used</param>
    /// <param name="parameters">The parameters to apply to the command string.</param>
    /// <returns>The result returned by the database after executing the command.</returns>
    public int ExecuteSqlCommand(string sql, int? timeout = null, params object[] parameters)
    {
        int? previousTimeout = null;
        if (timeout.HasValue)
        {
            //store previous timeout
            previousTimeout = ((IObjectContextAdapter) this).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout;
            ((IObjectContextAdapter) this).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = timeout;
        }

        var result = this.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql, parameters);

        if (timeout.HasValue)
        {
            //Set previous timeout back
            ((IObjectContextAdapter) this).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = previousTimeout;
        }

        //return result
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the code for your DbContext?

Comment: I have updated with what I believe you are asking for. I didn't dev this originally and being a newbie might not have gotten it correct.

Comment: I'm more looking for a class that derives from `DbContext`. How do you normally interact with the database? What object are you using?

Comment: Arrgggg I knew you would want the implementation as well but forgot to add it before saving changes.

Comment: Is the mapping class definitely `public class ExternalForumCredentialsMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<ExternalForumCredentials>`?

Comment: It is: public partial class ExternalForumCredentialsMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<ExternalForumCredentials> I've looked it over before posting to be sure. Note it is a partial class

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47805/discussion-between-rowan-freeman-and-user1278561)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have another class that has a relationship with `ExternalForumCredentials` and it hasn't be configured properly. EntityFramework will try its best to guess your conventions, so it's guessing that there is a `Customer_Id` that it can connect to.

Go to any maps that are using `ExternalForumCredentials` and configure them properly. For example:

```
this.HasMany(ef => ef.ExternalForumCredentials)
    .WithRequired()
    .HasForeignKey(ef => ef.Customer_Id);
```